# .NET Introspection VS Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, introspection

What is the difference between Introspection and Reflection in .NET

Comment: You probably need to be more specific with what you mean by "introspection".  You mean like Mono.Cecil?  Or FxCop?  Or something else specific?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introspection was introduced with [FxCop in 2004 as an alternative to Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc188721.aspx) :

> What's new in FxCop 1.30 is that it
>   now performs analysis through a
>   technique called Introspection. The
>   use of the Introspection engine allows
>   for much faster analysis and supports
>   multithreaded analysis. Unlike the
>   Reflection engine from previous
>   versions, in the Introspection engine
>   the assemblies you're analyzing are
>   not locked so you won't need to shut
>   down FxCop to do a fix and recompile
>   of those assemblies. Finally, the
>   Introspection engine offers a much
>   richer analysis infrastructure
>   compared to the Reflection engine.

Comment: This quote nails it, but doesn't directly call out the difference in the .NET world. Reflection can only target loaded assemblies and is limited in what it can do by the meta data in the CLI's type system. In comparison, introspection looks at external assemblies and can essentially access all the binary data in the file. This means introspection is not restricted by the type system, and can therefore infer additional details not exposed through the type system.

Answer (score 12):

They're two parts of the same whole.

Introspection refers to the ability of a class to look 'inside' itself and see, for example, what parameters a method takes, what the names of its members are, etc.

Reflection is the specific name for how .NET implements introspection.  Other languages may call it something different (C++ calls its limited introspection RTTI, for run-time type information).

Comment: +1 - I don't know how the other answer got more votes, this actually answers the question.

Comment: In .NET, specifically in Microsoft.Cci.dll, introspection refers to the process of inspecting an assembly without loading it into an ApplicationDomain. Reflection requires the assembly be loaded. In that sense, reflection looks at types that make up the current process, while introspection is a way for a process to look at assemblies that are not 'inside' itself